# OneDrive Running as a Service

Tags: microsoft-office-365

I am fairly sure this is not possible but just wanted to find out if anyone has managed to get this to work.

I wanted to find out if you can have One Drive running on a server, updating without the user profile that it was installed under needing to login.

The reason for this is I would like to automatically sync certain file shares directly to Sharepoint or One Drive.

Answer (score 2):

Not without using third party tools unfortunately.

A paid tool called "AlwaysUp" would be your best option, they have a tutorial on how to setup the tool with with OneDrive  here: http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunOneDriveAsAService.html